# How to set a specific time interval for different work shifts to retrieve data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two working shifts:  8:00:00 to 16:30:00 and 20:00:00 to 06:00:00.
I want to create a stored procedure that will retrieve data from an SQL table when I pass the date

this are my tables
Table1 Emp

```
ID   DateTime                 EmpID
47   2014-12-05 08:00:00      1111
47   2014-12-05 08:25:00      1235
47   2014-12-05 23:55:00      4569
47   2014-12-06 00:00:00      4563
47   2014-12-06 02:00:00      7412
59   2014-12-06 04:00:00      8523
59   2014-12-05 10:30:00      5632
```

Table2 Product

```
ID     DateTime              ProductMade
47     2014-12-05 11:00:00   Milk
47     2014-12-05 08:00:00   Juice
47     2014-12-06 00:00:00   Bread
47     2014-12-06 06:00:00   Cakes
```

query for shift 2 18:00 to 06:00

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table 1  as T1 
INNER JOIN Table_Product as Prod ON t1.ID=Prod.ID 
WHERE  T1.DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-8), 0) + '18:00'
AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-7), 0) + '06:00'
```

so this will get all the records that has the same ID matching

then i have to do another query for the first shift.

between 08:00 to 16:30

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table 1  AS T1
INNER JOIN
Table_Product AS Prod ON t1.ID=Prod.ID  
WHERE  DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T1.DateTime,110))=-1 AND DATEPART(HOUR,T1.DateTime) BETWEEN '07' AND '16'
```

How do i make this into one stored procdure and elminate having two queries.

Comment: Do you want to specify a date, and which shift, and get the data for it?

Comment: i dont want to pass in the date, i want to pass in like "-1" and then it must fetch yestedays data, and if i pass in "-2" it would fetch the days previous data. but im not sure how to specify the times 08:00:00 to 16:00:00 and 20:00:00 to 06:00:00, cause those times are fixed they wount change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [single query to retrieve data in sql for different shift patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354080/single-query-to-retrieve-data-in-sql-for-different-shift-patterns)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want it for a specific shift. Then you have to specify @Shift

```
Declare @Shift char(1),
        @days int
Set @Shift = 'A'  -- will only get information for SHIFT A. Change to B if you want the rest
Set @days = 1

Select * 
from Table1 t
where t.DateTime between 
case when @Shift = 'A' then DateAdd(hour, 8, Convert(date, GetDate() - @days)) 
else DateAdd(hour, 20, Convert(date, GetDate() - @days)) end 
and 
case when @Shift = 'A' then DateAdd(hour, 16, Convert(date, GetDate() - @days)) 
else DateAdd(hour, 30, Convert(date, GetDate() - @days)) end
```

Specify the Shift and a Date, and it should work.

You can always do something like this as well. This you only have to specify the number of days in the past, and it will retrieve the information and specify the Shift in the first Column

```
DECLARE @days int
SET @days = 1

Select case when DATEPART(hour, t.DateTime) between 8 and 16 then 'A' else 'B' end AS Shift, *
from Table1 t
where t.DateTime between DateAdd(hour, 8, Convert(date, GetDate() - @days))
and DateAdd(hour, 30, Convert(date, GetDate() - @days))
ORDER BY 1, t.DateTime
```

Comment: were you have @shift="A" how do i specify the time interval 08:00:00 to 16:00:00 cause i dont have it stored any were

Comment: i only have a DateTime column which i have to filter which is between 8 and 16:00:00 and which is between 20:00:00 and 06:00:00

Comment: [Don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  You'll select the wrong data at some point.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I'm not sure how you can get the wrong data? a DateTime is a floating point value. Your statement is totally ungrounded. If you said, don't use between on datetime when you are only specifying a date, then I would agree, but in the example that is used, both the date and time is specified in the between which means it is perfectly ok. If between is used properly it isn't the devil. The same with Guns.

Comment: Did you read the post?  The author goes into cases where (even with specifying the time) you can get incorrect data.  This isn't actually about date/time/timestamp values, it's an intrinsic property of how numbers are represented - any contiguous-range type (everything except an integer) has the same essential problem.  The fact that DateTime may be stored as a floating-point value is either irrelevant, or actively harmful: most modern hardware implements it _wider_ than software tends to, which changes the representations available (meaning things can go wrong slightly differently).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two shifts per day and the day shift begins before the night shift.  So, let's enumerate the shifts and let you choose the one(s) you want that way:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(sp.datetime as date)
                                order by sp.datetime
                               ) as shiftnumber
      from table t
     ) t
where DATEDIFF(day, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE), CAST(SP.DateTime as DATE)) = -1 and
      shiftnumber = 1;
```

Note that I also changed the date arithmetic.  The conversion to dates uses the built-in `DATE` type.  Converting a date to a string and back to a date is inelegant.

Comment: i cant seem to get this to work when i need to join multiple tables to each other

Comment: @John . . . Your question is about a single table.  This should work for more complex queries.  My first suggestion would be to use a CTE.

Comment: i have changed my question