# single query to retrieve data in sql for different shift patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two working shifts: 8:00:00 to 16:30:00 and 20:00:00 to 06:00:00. I want to create a stored procedure that will retrieve data from an SQL table when I pass the date

This is my tables Table1

```
  ID   DateTime                 EmpID  
  -------------------------------------
  47   2014-12-07 08:00:00      1111
  47   2014-12-07 15:25:00      1235 
  47   2014-12-07 23:55:00      4569
  47   2014-12-08 00:00:00      4563 
  47   2014-12-08 02:00:00      7412
  59   2014-12-08 04:00:00      8523 
  59   2014-12-05 10:30:00      5632
```

Table Product

```
ID      DateTime                  ProductMade
47      2014-12-07 11:00:00       Milk
47      2014-12-07 08:00:00       Juice
47      2014-12-08 00:00:00       Bread
47      2014-12-08 04:00:00       Cakes
47      2014-12-07 21:00:00       Juice
89      2014-12-01 04:00:00       bread
```

query for shift 2 18:00 to 06:00

```
select Count(EmpID) as ID,Count (ProductMade) ProductsTotal, Count(EmpID) * Count (ProductMade) as Total
from Table 1 as T1 
inner join Table_Product as Prod on t1.ID = Prod.ID 
where T1.DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-2), 0) + '18:00' and DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1), 0) + '06:00' and DepartmentID=47
```

So this will get all the records that has the same ID matching

Then I have to do another query for the first shift.

between 08:00 to 16:30

```
select Count(EmpID) as ID,Count (ProductMade) ProductsTotal, Count(EmpID) * Count (ProductMade) as Total
from Table 1 as T1 
inner join Table_Product as Prod on t1.ID = Prod.ID
where DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T1.DateTime,110))=-2 and DATEPART(HOUR,T1.DateTime) BETWEEN '07' AND '16' and DepartmentID=47
```

**OutPUT FirstShift** 08 :00 to 16:30

```
ID             ProductMade         Total
2                  2                  4
```

OutPut Second Shift 20:00 to 06:00

```
ID             ProductMade         Total
3                  3                  9
```

so the second shift request a the startdate of -2 and the end date of -1 this is the part thats different from the day shift. cause i will pass the number of days previous i want to go backwards from a select box

Comment: John, why do you ask EXACTLY the same question a week later? You have asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227474/how-to-set-a-specific-time-interval-for-different-work-shifts-to-retrieve-data/27227722#27227722

Comment: because i havent solved the problem and i wasnt sure how to promote the question, since there was no respone

Comment: John, there is more than one answer in your question, and they all work. How can you NOT solve it with those answers that was given?

Comment: John I saw that you changed the other question 2 days ago. Maybe you should change your approach on asking the questions. I'm sure the previous question had a valid answer. Mark the one that helped you as answered and ask the new question here to "escalate" the question, because currently it looks like a duplicate

Comment: jaques i never said that the answers didnt work,is it a crime if i couldnt solve it,i apologize for the inconvinience

Comment: You didn't except one as an answer, which means in our world that nothing was correct, and nothing helped you. If you accept an answer it means that it pointed you in the right direction and helped you getting closer to an answer. So mark an answer on the previous question, and go on with this one

Comment: Another question is, what do you want as a output?

Comment: @Jaques and i cant  mark an answer as useful because i dont have enough points to do so, so thats the only reason i didnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will product something in 1 go. I'm still not sure what output you are looking for. What does the DateTime in the Table_Product represent?

```
DECLARE @days int
SET @days = 4;

WITH Tab as (
Select case when DATEPART(hour, t.DateTime) between 8 and 16 then 'A' else 'B' end AS Shift, *
from Table1 t
where t.DateTime between DateAdd(hour, 8, Convert(datetime, Floor(Convert(float, Convert(datetime, GetDate())) - @days)))
and DateAdd(hour, 30, Convert(datetime, Floor(Convert(float, Convert(datetime, GetDate())) - @days)))
),
Prod as (
Select case when DATEPART(hour, t.DateTime) between 8 and 16 then 'A' else 'B' end AS Shift, *
from Table_Product t
where t.DateTime between DateAdd(hour, 8, Convert(datetime, Floor(Convert(float, Convert(datetime, GetDate())) - @days)))
and DateAdd(hour, 30, Convert(datetime, Floor(Convert(float, Convert(datetime, GetDate())) - @days))))
Select ID, ProductMake, Shift, Count(*), (Select Count(*) from Tab where ID = t1.ID and Shift = t1.Shift) Total from Prod t1 
GROUP BY ID, Shift, ProductMake
```

Comment: DateTime in the Table_Product represent? -what time the products were made.out put will be all the records for night shift separate and day shift separate

Comment: Ok, so what you want has nothing to do with the DateTime in the Table_product table. What is the DateTime in Table1 then, and STILL what are you expecting as an output.

Comment: i added the output expected now to the question

Comment: @john, thanks for that. Just a question, what have EmpID to do with it then? Why do you select in your statement from Table1 if you only interested in the `DateTime` and `ProductMade` from Table_Product? Is it possible to produce the OUTPUT relating to the data that you produced.

Comment: i need it because im counting how many people there is for that shift in that department, so i can find out how many employees took to make those products

Comment: Ok, So you want a productmade count, how many employees made that product grouped by shift.

Comment: I've changed my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: thank you that helped. except that i dont want it to group by it, because it wount give me the total for the day, cause it groups each empId thats the same together

Comment: @John, Why did you unselect this as the answer? You didn't select another answer again, Is there a reason why you unselected it?

Comment: sorry i didnt realise that happend

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
where ((@shift = 1 and t1.datetime between ... ) or (@shift = 2 and datediff ... ))
```